# writing plugin in eclipse for XML based project

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins

In our project the entire workflow is through xmls and there is some cryptic but systematic way to use specific syntax to achieve tasks. For example there is syntax to create objects, setting/getting attributes etc. But it is difficult for a beginner to be familiar with this all.

I want to know if it is possible to write some plugin that helps in things like auto completion or suggestion like normal java plugins or is it that plugins can be written for only compiler/interpreter based languages ?

Comment: Are you using the XML editor from WebTools? http://download.eclipse.org/webtools/repository/indigo/ It has functionality for code completion of XML.

Comment: Actually I am using Kepler, actually that answer is quite helpful. Thanks for your suggestion :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write editors for any sort of file. If the file is text based the Eclipse text editor APIs provides support for things like auto completion.

One of the examples available in the `New / Plug-in project' wizard creates a XML editor with some of theses features already included.